# How to create enums in Google Apps Script libraries?

Tags: google-apps-script, enums

I see that Apps Script uses a lot of enums, predefined by Google (e.g. [`Enum MimeType`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type)).

How can I define my own Enum types so they are shown on my own libraries?

I can add a standard enum like this.

```
var size = {
  SMALL: 1,
  MEDIUM: 2,
  LARGE: 3,
};

var mySize = size.MEDIUM;
```

and it works properly, but if I add my project as a library, the enum is not listed as a standard enum, but as an object type:

[image: Enum shown as object]

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use size as an enum as long as it is in global scope and you precede with the namespace, for example MyLibrary.size.MEDIUM

Comment: Read about documenting your scripts with JSDoc for autocompletion

Comment: I've used JSDoc convention as shown here: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-enum.html but still get a "object" and not enum type (and autocompletion does not work).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893927/writing-jsdoc-documentation-on-methods-inside-a-class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158745/google-apps-script-auto-generated-library-documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#best_practices (note that only `@param` and `@returns` have stated support. Consider developing locally with typescript and using a third party tool to bundle your library code directly