# How can I annotate that argument is a class and has certain static method?

Tags: javascript, class, google-apps-script, ide, jsdoc

I want to pass a class to function and call its static method. The code works but autocomplete does not. How can I annotate that argument has certain static method?

```js
class Parent {
  static staticMethod() {
    console.log("static method")
  }
}
class Child1 extends Parent {}
class Child2 extends Parent {}

/** @param {Parent} child */
function doSomething(child) {
  child.staticMethod(); // no autocomplete
}
doSomething(Child1)
```

[image]

#### ADDED

Marked as duplicate and suggested inappropriate question; it is talked about library but I ask about what happens in a single file itself.

[Writing jsdoc documentation on methods inside a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893927/writing-jsdoc-documentation-on-methods-inside-a-class)

Comment: Why pass a `Class` around as an argument when you can reference its static methods directly?

Comment: @TheAddonDepot  Maybe there are multiple `Child` classes, each with it's own `staticMethod` acting differently

Comment: @TheMaster If polymorphism is the goal, as in your example, wouldn't it make more sense to use an instance method instead of a static one? Polymorphic static methods just don't make sense to me from an OOP standpoint. It's not typically a feature in OOP languages (but Javascript, being the chimera that it is, somehow allows for it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`typeof`](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System):

```
/**
 * @param {typeof Parent} child
 */
```