# JSDoc function type hints are different when referenced function is imported from library

Tags: google-apps-script, jsdoc

I have the following function in my Google Apps Script project.

```
/**
 * Get data from specified sheet.
 * 
 * @param {string} sheetName sheet to retrieve data from 
 * @param {number} [dataStartRow=2] row number where data begins
 * @param {number} [dataStartCol=1] dataStartCol column number where data begins
 * @return {Array[]}
 */
function getSheetData(sheetName, dataStartRow = 2, dataStartCol = 1) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName));
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1; // Excluding header row
  var numCols = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(dataStartRow, dataStartCol, numRows, numCols);

  return dataRange.getValues();
}
```

If I have this function in my project, I get the following tip, which is the desired result:

[image: correct tip]

However, if I put this function into a separate project (let's call it `Helper`), add Helper as a library, and type `Helper.getSheetData()` - I get the following tip:

[image: incorrect tip]

I would like to keep this function in a separate project, so any help to achieve the correct type hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this will help:https://stackoverflow.com/a/15161288/7215091